# Beamer: Using \label for blocks adds vertical space

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tcolorbox, labels

When adding a `\label` to a block in the `beamer` class, additional vertical space is inserted before the content.

This doesn't happen with the default block template, but setting using the `rounded` template introduces the space.

As far as I can see, a `pgfpicture` is used for the rounded blocks and afaik, also the `tcolorbox` package uses `pgfpicter`. Indeed, also for `tcolorbox`es, the vertical space is added. So my guess is, it has something to do with that.

---

**How can I avoid this behaviour?**

A simple but not very clean workaround would be to add a negative `\vspace` but I'd rather understand the origin of this …

Looking forward to your answers :)

---

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red!5}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=red!40}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Regular block}\label{thm:1}
            I have a label.
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Regular block}
            I don't have a label.
        \end{block}

        \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

        \begin{block}{Round block}\label{thm:2}%
            I have a label.
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Round block}
            I don't have a label.
        \end{block}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={tcolorbox}]\label{thm:3}
            I have a label.
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={tcolorbox}]
            I don't have a label.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Produces:[image]

---

**Update:** As suggested by @koleygr, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/541) in the `beamer` repo on GitHub.

Comment: See the tcolobox manual, it has a whole section about labels and references

Comment: @daleif ... I think you didn't read the problem ... (Sorry if I am wrong... I will delete this comment in 5 mins)

Comment: @koleygr I did read the question. And is referring to the manual as tcolorbox has its own build in handling of labels, you just have to pass is as a key option, not at the start of the env

Comment: ok @daleif... Thanks for your answer ...b ut it refers to blocks too without tcolorbox and the problem seems specific to beamer but tcolorbox can be used outside of it without this problem... (Just explained myself)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @daleif. Indeed, I added the tcolorbox example mainly to support my guees that the issue is within `pgfpicture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Fix by redefining the environments:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red!5}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=red!40}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newlength\myFSize
\newlength\myFontSize
\makeatletter
\def\ReadFSize{%
\setlength{\myFSize}{\f@size pt}
\setlength{\myFontSize}{0.5\myFSize}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{emptyLabelCounter}

\newenvironment{myRBlock}[2]{\def\X{#2}\begin{block}{#1}\ifx\X\empty\stepcounter{emptyLabelCounter}\label{labelEmpty:\X}\else\label{#2}\fi\ReadFSize\vskip-\myFontSize\par}{\end{block}\vskip-\myFontSize}
\newenvironment{myTcolorbox}[2][]{\ReadFSize\par\begin{tcolorbox}[#1]\ifx\X\empty\stepcounter{emptyLabelCounter}\label{labelEmpty:\X}\else\label{#2}\fi\vskip-0.6\myFontSize}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Regular block}\label{thm:1}%
            I have a label.
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Regular block}
            I don't have a label.
        \end{block}

        \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

        \begin{myRBlock}{Round block}{thm:2}
            I have a label.
        \end{myRBlock}
        \Large
        \begin{myRBlock}{Round block}{}
            I don't have a label.
        \end{myRBlock}

        \begin{myTcolorbox}[title={tcolorbox}]{thm:3}%
            I have a label.
        \end{myTcolorbox}
        \begin{myTcolorbox}[title={tcolorbox}]{}
            I don't have a label.
        \end{myTcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

PS: I added a label argument to each definition and an auto-label if empty.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the convenient fix! Do you know _why_ there is a need for it?

Comment: @Hirsch ... Sorry ... it is just a Fix without reading the manual of tcolorbox at all (I don't use it). Possibly it is a bug of beamer's block as far as I understood and we could report it to the authors.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the effort! I'll open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Nice ... Then add the solution here and accept it as the real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use at your own risk (from https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/541#issuecomment-552993755 ):

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red!5}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=red!40}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@inserttarget#1{%
  \ifbeamer@inframe%
    #1%
  \else% defer to next frame
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@framehypertargets\expandafter{\beamer@framehypertargets#1}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Regular block}\label{thm:1}
            I have a label.
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Regular block}
            I don't have a label.
        \end{block}

        \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

        \begin{block}{Round block}\label{thm:2}%
            I have a label.
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Round block}
            I don't have a label.
        \end{block}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={tcolorbox}]\label{thm:3}
            I have a label.
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={tcolorbox}]
            I don't have a label.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]